# Issues in Facebook Install ads for my android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to have Facebook Install ads for my android app.

Following the guidelines explained in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/. I have also downloaded Facebook-android-sdk from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/archive/sdk-version-3.0.1.b.zip

As provided in the above guidelines, for this integration I have to write the following code in my **onResume()** of all activities:

```
com.facebook.Settings.publishInstallAsync(this, MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
```

For the above integration, I need Facebook SDK jar. So I have imported the above project (Facebook-android-sdk) to my eclipse IDE and exported it as a jar file. I have added this new jar to my libs directory also included in Java Build Path (libraries) of my android app.

Once after the above step, when I try to debug or run my application, I am receiving the following error in console:

```
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/facebook/android/AsyncFacebookRunner$1;
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:703)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:577)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2013-02-21 18:35:09 - com.org.product.view.welcome.WelcomeView] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I am helpless with the above error and I am not able to debug/run my app.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to duplicated dependency issue in android-support-v4.jar and my new facebook-android-sdk.

I have created a new jar from the facebook-android-sdk (which uses only the necessary items needed for me) and that fixed.

Thank You.